# Sentiment analysis probabilities

Tags: probability, sentiment-analysis

I'm looking into a [Kaggle dataset](https://www.kaggle.com/c/two-sigma-financial-news/data) of news article with three columns for the results of sentiment analysis for news items, each about a different company. The columns present the results of probability that the sentiment of the news item was positive, negative or neutral for the company discussed:

[image: Extract from the data]

Overall sentiment (sentimentClass) is determined by the highest probability. But in that way we cannot distinguish an article of 0.55 from 0.80 probability of positive sentiment. Is there a better way to combine/weigh these probabilities to take such differences into account?